# Message is not sending if I don't specify the Queue, TopicExchange, Binding in SpringBootApplication

Tags: spring-boot, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I tried to send the message as  follows:

```
rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend("my.exchange", "my.queue", "Test Message");
```

And tried to receive the message as follows:

```
@RabbitListener(bindings = @QueueBinding(value = @Queue(value = "my.queue", durable = "true"), exchange = @Exchange(value = "my.exchange", durable = "true", type = ExchangeTypes.TOPIC)))
public void receiveAuditMessage(String message) {
    log.info("Received <" + message + ">");     
}
```

It was not working.

But if I specify the Queue, TopicExchange, Binding in @SpringBootApplication then its working fine.

```
@Bean
Queue queue() {
    return new Queue("my.queue");
}

@Bean
TopicExchange exchange() {
    return new TopicExchange("my.exchange");
}

@Bean
Binding binding(Queue queue, TopicExchange exchange) {
    return BindingBuilder.bind(queue).to(exchange).with("my.queue");
}
```

Is it mandatory to specify Queue, TopicExchange, Binding in SpringBootApplication ?
If yes, then how to specify multiple Queue, TopicExchange, Binding in SpringBootApplication ?

Please help me here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first case, you are creating a queue and exchange, but no routing key for the binding; you need a routing key for a TOPIC exchange...

```
@RabbitListener(bindings = @QueueBinding(value = @Queue(value = "my.queue", durable = "true"),
        exchange = @Exchange(value = "my.exchange", durable = "true", type = ExchangeTypes.TOPIC),
        key = "my.queue"))
public void receiveAuditMessage(String message) {
    System.out.println("Received <" + message + ">");
}
```

Or `key = "#"` to get all messages.